# How to test unlikely concurrent scenarios?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go, concurrency, code-coverage

For example, map access like this:

```
func (pool *fPool) fetch(url string) *ResultPromise {
    pool.cacheLock.RLock()
    if rp, pres := pool.cache[url]; pres {
        pool.cacheLock.RUnlock()
        return rp
    }
    pool.cacheLock.RUnlock()
    pool.cacheLock.Lock()
    if rp, pres := pool.cache[url]; pres {
        pool.cacheLock.Unlock()
        // Skip adding url if someone snuck it in between RUnlock an Lock
        return rp
    }
    rp := newPromise()
    pool.cache[url] = rp
    pool.cacheLock.Unlock()
    pool.c <- fetchWork{rp, url}
    return rp
}
```

Here, the contents of the second `if` condition are not covered. However, by placing breakpoints it's trivial to end up in that block.

The example isn't contrived, because:

1. If we skip the `RLock`, the map will be unnecessarily locked when the workload is mostly reads.
2. If we skip the second `if`,the most expensive work (handled by `pool.c <- fetchWork{rp, url}` in this case) can happen more than once for the same key, which is unacceptable.

Comment: To your first point, I don't think it matters; the "workload" in question is a single key lookup in your map. Given that, you can just dump the entire first (read-only) section - everything from the `RLock` to the second `RUnlock`.

Comment: @Adrian, that would mean that every lookup would `Lock`(Alone!) the map. Meaning that it would block not only other such lookups, but also be blocked by long-running `RLock`s, and block future `RLock`ers until the long `RLock` and then the lookup here clear.

Comment: Does the application hold the lock for a long period, or is it just add / remove values from the map?

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis and? In the case where it would currently only RLock, it would only lock for the time it takes to do a single map lookup - a couple of nanos. Depending on how often the first check actually bails out early, it's probably actually faster to skip the first RLocked test and just do it once Locked.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I cannot guarantee that other functions won't hold an `RLock` while iterating over the entire map, or even worse, synchronously do stuff to some values while iterating.

Comment: @Adrian, the point is the first check will bail a lot of the time, so no `Lock` will be attempted at all. The point is there can be many `RLock`ers coming and going simultaneously, but only one `Lock` at a time. If we needlessly `Lock` every lookup, the queue will become like stripy bacon, and there will be no read concurrency.

Comment: I still don't think it matters. It's a single map read. Maybe just try load testing it with the initial RLocked section commented out.

Comment: It benchmarks worse :D Of course, real world loads won't exercise this function as much, but you know what they say about premature optimization - **You gotta do it!™**

Comment: It just seems like the correct design for this structure, to make it and forget.
But I have 3 of these function on 2 different maps, and it's eating at the coverage. Hence, the question.

Comment: `and block future RLockers until the long RLock and then the lookup here clear.`

Lock already blocks concurrent RLock calls.  Lock is a single global lock, nothing else can acquire _either_ type of lock while it is active.  You can only acquire a Lock() if there are no locks of either type, and you can only acquire an RLock if there are no Locks already present.  The only concurrent locks allowed are multiple RLocks.  So your long-running lock already blocks concurrent reads, and the read portion itself is trivially fast, so there's little benefit to using an RLock instead of a Lock.

Comment: @Kaedys long-running *`RLock`. Which wouldn't block. Unless we laid our trivial `Lock` on top.

Comment: Fair, though I'm assuming you're referring to some _other_ RLock, because this one definitely isn't long running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## I. Mocking `pool.cacheLock.Lock()`

One way to cover that branch would be to mock `pool.cacheLock.Lock()`, and the mocked version could insert the `url` into the map. So checking again after this call, it would be found and execution would enter the body of the 2nd `if` statement.

### Mocking by using interface

One way to mock `pool.cacheLock.Lock()` would be to make `pool.cacheLock` an interface, and in tests you can set a mocked value whose `Lock()` method will do the "dirty insert" into the map.

Here's a simplified version of your code that uses an interface for `pool.cacheLock`:

```
type rwmutex interface {
    Lock()
    RLock()
    RUnlock()
    Unlock()
}

type fPool struct {
    cache     map[string]string
    cacheLock rwmutex
}

func (pool *fPool) fetch(url string) string {
    pool.cacheLock.RLock()
    if rp, pres := pool.cache[url]; pres {
        pool.cacheLock.RUnlock()
        return rp
    }
    pool.cacheLock.RUnlock()
    pool.cacheLock.Lock()
    if rp, pres := pool.cache[url]; pres {
        pool.cacheLock.Unlock()
        // Skip adding url if someone snuck it in between RUnlock an Lock
        return rp
    }
    rp := url + "~data"
    pool.cache[url] = rp
    pool.cacheLock.Unlock()
    return rp
}
```

Its normal usage would be:

```
pool := fPool{
    cache:     map[string]string{},
    cacheLock: &sync.RWMutex{},
}
fmt.Println(pool.fetch("http://google.com"))
```

And a test case that will trigger the body of the 2nd `if`:

```
type testRwmutex struct {
    sync.RWMutex // Embed RWMutex so we don't have to implement everything
    customLock   func()
}

func (trw *testRwmutex) Lock() {
    trw.RWMutex.Lock()
    if trw.customLock != nil {
        trw.customLock()
    }
}

func TestFPoolFetch(t *testing.T) {
    trw := &testRwmutex{RWMutex: sync.RWMutex{}}
    pool := &fPool{
        cache:     map[string]string{},
        cacheLock: trw,
    }

    exp := "http://google.com~test"
    trw.customLock = func() {
        pool.cache["http://google.com"] = exp
    }

    if got := pool.fetch("http://google.com"); got != exp {
        t.Errorf("Expected: %s, got: %s", exp, got)
    }
}
```

### Mocking by using a function field

Another way to mock `pool.cacheLock.Lock()` would be to "outsource" this functionality to a field of function type, which tests can replace to a function which–besides calling this–also does the "dirty insert".

Again your simplified example:

```
func NewFPool() *fPool {
    mu := &sync.RWMutex{}
    return &fPool{
        cache:     map[string]string{},
        cacheLock: mu,
        lock:      mu.Lock,
    }
}

type fPool struct {
    cache     map[string]string
    cacheLock *sync.RWMutex
    lock      func()
}

func (pool *fPool) fetch(url string) string {
    pool.cacheLock.RLock()
    if rp, pres := pool.cache[url]; pres {
        pool.cacheLock.RUnlock()
        return rp
    }
    pool.cacheLock.RUnlock()
    pool.lock()
    if rp, pres := pool.cache[url]; pres {
        pool.cacheLock.Unlock()
        // Skip adding url if someone snuck it in between RUnlock an Lock
        return rp
    }
    rp := url + "~data"
    pool.cache[url] = rp
    pool.cacheLock.Unlock()
    return rp
}
```

Normal usage would be:

```
pool := NewFPool()
fmt.Println(pool.fetch("http://google.com"))
```

And a test case that will trigger the body of the 2nd `if`:

```
func TestFPoolFetch(t *testing.T) {
    pool := NewFPool()
    oldLock := pool.lock

    exp := "http://google.com~test"
    pool.lock = func() {
        oldLock()
        pool.cache["http://google.com"] = exp
    }

    if got := pool.fetch("http://google.com"); got != exp {
        t.Errorf("Expected: %s, got: %s", exp, got)
    }
}
```

## II. Using a simple `test` flag

The idea here is that to support easy testing you build a simple `test` flag into the implementation of `fPool` (e.g. it can be a field of `fPool`), and the code you want to test deliberately checks for this flag:

```
type fPool struct {
    cache     map[string]string
    cacheLock *sync.RWMutex
    test      bool
}

func (pool *fPool) fetch(url string) string {
    pool.cacheLock.RLock()
    if rp, pres := pool.cache[url]; pres {
        pool.cacheLock.RUnlock()
        return rp
    }
    pool.cacheLock.RUnlock()
    pool.cacheLock.Lock()
    if rp, pres := pool.cache[url]; pres || pool.test {
        pool.cacheLock.Unlock()
        // Skip adding url if someone snuck it in between RUnlock an Lock
        return rp
    }
    rp := url + "~data"
    pool.cache[url] = rp
    pool.cacheLock.Unlock()
    return rp
}
```

Now if you want to test the body of the 2nd `if`, all you gotta do is:

```
func TestFPoolFetch(t *testing.T) {
    pool := NewFPool()
    pool.test = true

    exp := ""
    if got := pool.fetch("http://google.com"); got != exp {
        t.Errorf("Expected: %s, got: %s", exp, got)
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool use of embedding!

Comment: I think the first option is best, being able to use a normal `RWMutex` in normal use and its normal methods. Even if `fPool` has a constructor, I can always go in and shove the fake `rwmutex` in afterwards.

Comment: Is there a runtime performance impact of using an interface instead of concrete `RWMutex`?

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis Also added another method using a `test` flag.

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis There might be a tiny overhead, but it won't be significant compared to all the things that happen inside `RWMutex`.

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis And whenever in doubt, benchmark.