# How can I generalize this map + sync.RWMutex pattern?

Tags: dictionary, generics, go, mutex

How can I generalize this map access/modification pattern, considering there aren't generics in go?

```
func (pool *fPool) fetch(url string) *ResultPromise {
    pool.cacheLock.RLock()
    if rp, pres := pool.cache[url]; pres {
        pool.cacheLock.RUnlock()
        return rp
    }
    pool.cacheLock.RUnlock()
    pool.cacheLock.Lock()
    if rp, pres := pool.cache[url]; pres {
        pool.cacheLock.Unlock()
        // Skip adding url if someone snuck it in between RUnlock an Lock
        return rp
    }
    rp := newPromise()
    pool.cache[url] = rp
    pool.cacheLock.Unlock()
    pool.c <- fetchWork{rp, url} // Expensive/atomic work
    return rp
}
```

It's used for multiple maps of different types, for obvious reasons.

Maybe it's a poor solution?

Disclaimer: it's the same code from **[How to test unlikely concurrent scenarios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930732/how-to-test-unlikely-concurrent-scenarios)**, sorry.

Comment: There's only two ways to "generalize" in Go, which are actually the same way: interfaces.  You can either define an interface that represents the shared behavior of the types you need to store, or you can use an empty interface and then either type-assert it at the receiving end, or type switch it.  The types being asserted/switched to can be either concrete types (ex. `*ResultPromise`), or an interface that represents that type's (or multiple types') method set, which also allows mocking.

Comment: To expand on the above, it looks like the type fetch wants to work on is an interface with- RLock(), RUnlock(), Lock(), Unlock(), Get(), Put(), AssignMore().  An interface type can't be a receiver, so fetch would change from being a method to being a function. Of course, there are other ways of abstracting this further, but you could start there.

Comment: @JonahB but that's talking about replacing the map with a different data structure. I want to do this to maps of things other than `*ResultPromise`. Meaning the argument type to Put() and the return type of `Get()`, `newPromise()`, and `fetch()` itself would change.

Comment: @Kaedys I am new to go, as you probably noticed, but I thought this could be solved by code generation?

Comment: It could, but code generation is generally rather brittle.  The usual solution to needing a "generic" cache or the like is to use empty interface returns, and then either type assert at the receiving end, or wrap the cache Get calls in a helper that does the type assertion and converts a type assertion failure into an `error` type instead.  Even the standard library [uses this style](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Pool)

Comment: Thank you. I just consistently, in my few days of experience hear that empty interfaces are only for the high level scripting because the performance is _catastrophic_. Big thanks for the link to standard library example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that generics are available, I decided to revisit Go, and answer my question. This is what I came up with:

```golang
type Cached[K comparable, R any] struct {
    cache map[K]R
    fn    func(K) R
    lock  sync.RWMutex
}

func NewCached[K comparable, R any](
    fn func(K) R) *Cached[K, R] {
    return &Cached[K, R]{
        cache: make(map[K]R),
        fn:    fn,
        lock:  sync.RWMutex{},
    }
}

func (c *Cached[K, R]) Get(k K) R {
    c.lock.RLock()
    if rp, pres := c.cache[k]; pres {
        c.lock.RUnlock()
        return rp
    }
    c.lock.RUnlock()
    c.lock.Lock()
    defer c.lock.Unlock()
    if rp, pres := c.cache[k]; pres {
        // Skip adding key if someone else snuck it in between RUnlock and Lock
        return rp
    }
    rp := c.fn(k)
    c.cache[k] = rp
    return rp
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>

(Currently linking to `?v=gotip` and not release because generics still aren't released or something? idk)](https://go.dev/play/p/ht1NpBYAnTY?v=gotip)

*[previous](https://go.dev/play/p/ocn_O2P19Mj?v=gotip)*